# how to add folder to virtual apache2 host on ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have created a virtual apache 2 host on ubuntu 16.04 using follow

```
        1) sudo mkdir -p /var/www/share.com/public_html
        2) sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/share.com/public_html
        3) sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
        4) sudo nano /var/www/share.com/public_html/index.html
        5) inside index.html following is added
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>WELCOME!!1</title>
                    </head>
                    </html>
        6) cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/share.com.conf
        7) sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/share.com.conf
             inside share.com.conf
                       serverAdmin info@share.com
                       serverName share.com
                       Documentroot var/www/share.com/public_html
        8) sudo a2ensite share.com.conf
        9) sudo a2disite 000-default.conf
        10) sudo service apache2 restart
        11) sudo nano /etc/hosts
        inside host file
          127.0.0.1       ubuntu-controller       ubuntu-controller
            127.0.0.1       localhost
            127.0.1.1       vagrant
            192.168.10.10 share.com
            127.0.0.1 testsite.lk
            ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
            ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
            ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

After doing as above from the browser if i type 192.168.10.10 i get the page as:

[image]

Actualy i should see in the browser the index.html content as "WELCOME" which is not displayed and also if i try to open as "www.share.com" nothing get displayed. Secondly i want to add folders inside the host So, please help me how can i add folders on the server.

Answer (score 0):

> After doing as above from the browser if I type 192.168.10.10 i get
>   the page as...

That is the expected behavior, since you are typing the IP and not `share.com`.  When a request comes into the server, Apache matches the `Host` field of the incoming HTTP request to the `ServerName`, so an IP address will not match `share.com`.

Also `a2disite 000-default.conf`, does not disable the default directory. Apache uses this as a place to run when nothing matches.  You will want to put some kind of simple HTML file that does nothing, or shows an error, not the default page.

In your Apache configuration you have:

```
serverName share.com
Documentroot var/www/share.com/public_html
```

It should be:

```
ServerName share.com
DocumentRoot var/www/share.com/public_html
```

> Actualy I should see in the browser the index.html content as
>   "WELCOME" which is not displayed and also if I try to open as
>   "www.share.com" nothing get displayed.

You need to type `share.com`, so it matches the `ServerName`.